# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with zero angle?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces

> **Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:**
>
> If $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are vectors in a real inner product space $V$, then $$|\left\langle\textbf{u},\textbf{v}\right\rangle|\leq||\textbf{u}||\ ||\textbf{v}||$$

What will happen with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality if the angle between the two vectors is zero?

Comment: Algebraically, what does it mean for the angle between $u$ and $v$ to be $0$? Answer this and the answer to your question will present itself.

Comment: @GitGud  $|<\textbf{u},\textbf{v}>| = ||\textbf{u}|| ||\textbf{v}||$ ? I thought this, but it seemed a bit simple, considering the space left open in the past question paper in which one could answer it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the definition of the angle $\alpha\in[0,\pi]$ between $u,v$ is:
$$
\cos\alpha = \frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|u\| \|v\|}
$$

so  $\alpha =0 $ iff
$$
1=\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|u\| \|v\|}\iff
\langle u,v\rangle = \|u\| \|v\|
$$

Answer (score 1):

When angle between $v,w$ is $0$ (in other words $v=\alpha w$ or $w=\alpha v$ for some $\alpha$), then (if $w = \alpha v$):

$$|\langle w,v\rangle|=|\langle \alpha v,v\rangle|=|\alpha\langle v,v\rangle|=|\alpha|\|v\|^2=|\alpha|\|v\|\|v\|=\|\alpha v\|\|v\|=\|w\|\|v\|$$

The same with $v=\alpha w$.